# SSRS 2008 R2 Row/Column Group Issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am using Row Group And Column Group in SSRS 2008 R2.
I have design the report contain two row groups(et.Pixel、Name) and one column group(et.Date). 
Preview Report as bellow:

```
      |      Date1        |    Date2          |  Date2            |
Pixel | Name | Input | Ng | Name | Input | Ng | Name | Input | Ng |
      | XXX1 | 1000  | 2  |      |       |    |      |       |    |
      |      |       |    | YYY1 | 2000  | 1  |      |       |    |
 2M   |      |       |    | YYY2 | 1000  | 2  |      |       |    |
      |      |       |    | YYY3 | 3000  | 5  |      |       |    |
      |      |       |    |      |       |    | ZZZ1 |  800  | 2  |
      |      |       |    |      |       |    | ZZZ2 |  500  | 3  |
      |Total | 1000  | 2  |Total | 6000  | 8  |Total | 1300  | 5  |
```

My question is, How do I get the Preview Report don't show white space column in report.
For example:

```
      |      Date1        |    Date2          |  Date2            |
Pixel | Name | Input | Ng | Name | Input | Ng | Name | Input | Ng |
      | XXX1 | 1000  | 2  | YYY1 | 2000  | 1  | ZZZ1 |  800  | 2  |
 2M   |      |       |    | YYY2 | 1000  | 2  | ZZZ2 |  500  | 3  |
      |      |       |    | YYY3 | 3000  | 5  |      |       |    |
      |Total | 1000  | 2  |Total | 6000  | 8  |Total | 1300  | 5  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the grouping by **name** which is causing the issue that you are having. Since the name is different they won't be on the same line.

On the plus side, you can probably work around this. If the data is like you display it, I would group on the numeric number in the name instead of the whole name.

```
=MID(Fields!Name.Value, 4, LEN(Fields!Name.Value) - 3)
```

Of course you couldn't have XXX and YYY data on the same date with this expression otherwise you would have multiple rows.

Comment: By your suggest,i got a mind to solution this issue. Add row_id (et.row_number() over(partition by pixel,date order by pixel,date)) and modify name Grouping method as row_id,it will work.Thanks.